# SimpleLogin facebook wont login

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

i'm using the firebase simpleLogin for facebook login, but there seem to be an issue. i'm not sure how to debug this. What seem to be the issue here?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02c331e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x029b28e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02bf9376 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 390
3   CoreFoundation                      0x02c26c29 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 73
4   app                                 0x000257b5 ParseUserData + 373
5   app                                 0x000982a6 __38-[LoginViewController actionFacebook:]_block_invoke + 358
6   app                                 0x00148647 __89-[FirebaseSimpleLogin loginToFacebookAppWithId:permissions:audience:withCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke245 + 83
7   app                                 0x00149068 __86-[FirebaseSimpleLogin requestFacebookAccountWithPermissions:audience:appId:withBlock:]_block_invoke + 245
8   Accounts                            0x012cc91f __69-[ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 85
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x02f917b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02fa64d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02f92fe0 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 202
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02fa64d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02f94eb7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 291
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02f95127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x032d5dab _pthread_wqthread + 336
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x032d9cce start_wqthread + 30
)
```

Comment: have a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263695/i-am-not-able-to-fetch-user-data-from-facebook-in-ios/20264367#20264367

Comment: don't insert nil value of object in nsdictionary